# What data structures can Iterators be used on?

Tags: java, arrays, iterator

Just took a quiz in a CS course I'm in, and I wanted to compare my thoughts with what you guys know. The question asked "Which of the following data structures can be stepped through with an Iterator?" and the options were "ArrayList, an array-based implementation of the QueueADT, and an array-based implementation of the StackADT." You could select more than one, but I only selected ArrayList -- I thought that iterators could only step through Object data structures, and since the ADTs were implemented using arrays, an Iterator couldn't be used on them. Is my thinking incorrect here?

Comment: This seems like a question that asks about implementation details of abstract data structures. It's kinda strange and confusing, considering that you need to think about what `Iterator` is and not what "iterating" is or abstract data structures are. Abstract data structures provide functions to work on the data and if there are no functions so that you can iterate it, you cannot iterate it. But with implementation details, you can "hack" it and add functionality. It's obvious: If all 3 are array-based, you simply iterate the array. That's it. If not, it starts e.g. getting trickier for stacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a bit, eh... unclear.

### The for-each sense

If the sense is 'what can you use the for-each construct on', then the answer is: instances of `Iterable`, and arrays:

```
int[] a = new int[10];
for (int b : a) { .... }
```

is legal, even though `a` is not iterable. An `Iterable` is defined as: has the method `public Iterator iterator() { .. }`. So Iterators aren't iterable, but something like `ArrayList` implements `Iterable`.

In that sense, arrays are a lot like iterables: You can step through them. Just, not with an iterator, unless...

### The 'an iterator could be made' sense

Hey, I can make ya an iterator that iterates over an array, no problem:

```
String[] arr = new String[10];

return new Iterator<String>() {
   private int idx = 0;
   public boolean hasNext() { return idx < arr.length; }
   public String next() { return arr[idx++]; }
};
```

So, can you iterate through an array using an iterator? I guess so. Only took 5 lines.

### The 'array-based' doesn't mean 'array' interpretation

ArrayList is an array-based implementation of List. Hence the name `ArrayList`. It is iterable and will return iterators. That implementation looks a lot like what I wrote in the previous section.

Assuming QueueAdt is a reference to [this](http://faculty.washington.edu/moishe/javademos/ch07%20Code/jss2/QueueADT.java) - then `QueueADT` is analogous to `List` (an interface that just defines operations), and "an array-based implementation of QueueADT" would then be analogous to `ArrayList`. However, one crucial difference is that the List interface itself demands that any implementation is `Iterable<T>`, whereas the `QueueADT` interface doesn't require this, assuming I linked to the right code. Nevertheless, implementations (subtypes) can add extra features if they want. This is perfectly legit:

```
public class ArrayQueueAdt<T> implements QueueADT<T>, Iterable<T> {
    private final Object[] array;

    @Override public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        // something like the above
    }

    public void enqueue(T element) {
        // impl here
    }

    // etcetera
}
```

### In the 'arrays are Iterators or Iterable' sense

Then no. Arrays do not implement `Iterable`, and they do not have an `iterator()` method. The idiomatic java way to turn an array into an iterable or iterator is: `Arrays.asList(theArray)`, which is lightweight (doesn't copy anything) and is Iterable. `Arrays.asList(theArray).iterator()` similarly, is a lightweight (no copies) way to get it. So, maybe?

They don't *HAVE* to (because QueueADT doesn't declare it, whereas List does).

So, the answer is pretty much ¯\*(ツ)*/¯  I guess yes, because the answer in all these senses is yes, or maybe.

Comment: That makes sense -- I just considered make an iterator for an array pointless, and as such it shouldn't be done. If the question is just asking " _can_ an iterator be made for it?" Then yeah, all of them should have been selected. Thanks for such a comprehensive answer!

Comment: There's plenty of reason to do that. Lots of APIs want you to provide a `Collection<T>`, `Iterable<T>` or `Iterator<T>` - the point is abstraction: The API just needs to walk through a bunch of items, and the caller can then provide this regardless of what the caller actually has. So, if the caller has an array, and you have some utility method that searches through them for something, tada. A reason to wrap an array into an iterable. Usually the type for 'I just wanna walk through it' is `Collection<T>`. Soo.. `Arrays.asList(arr)` does that.